# the dispatch_after function never runs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to execute the following code, however the code in the dispatch_after method isn't running.  In the instance that I am running the else condition will always be true, and if I put a print statement before the dispatch_after it prints as expected.  Is there any reason someone can see that would stop it from running?

```
func afterAsyncRun(ref:FIRDatabaseReference, ended:Bool, count:Int, batterName:UILabel, pitcherName:UILabel) {
    var count2 = count
    while(ended != true) {
        if(count2 < 2) {
            print("current count is < 2")

        } else {
            let seconds = 2.0
            let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
            let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

            dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                //below is the delayed code
                ref.child(String(count-2)).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2) in
                    var hitterRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Hitter")
                    var pitcherRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Pitcher")
                    batterName.text = (String(hitterRef.childSnapshotForPath("/fName")) + " " + String(hitterRef.childSnapshotForPath("/lname")))
                    pitcherName.text = (String(pitcherRef.childSnapshotForPath("/fName")) + " " + String(pitcherRef.childSnapshotForPath("/lname")))

                print("successful delay")

                })
                count2++

            })//this is where the delay code ends

        }//this is where the else loop ends
    }//while loops ends
    print("labels updated")
}
```

When I run without the nano second multiplier, still nothing happens.  However after waiting a few seconds and killing the run I get the following error:

```
2017-05-25 10:10:55.191 Test[31038:2390189] XPC connection interrupted
2017-05-25 10:10:55.167 Test[31038:2390038] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x106fb1b40> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x106fb1ef0> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

Comment: It's a Swift 2 edition?

Comment: Are you sure else part is executed ? Print a message in the else before `dispatch_after` statement.

Comment: @user1046037 I have already done that, and it prints, which is why I am confused

Comment: Can u try without the nano sec multiplication or a smaller value ?

Comment: @user1046037 I just did that and edited the question to show the results

Comment: Can you add a print statement inside dispatch_after. Comment out all firebase code inside.

Comment: @user1046037 already did, doesn't print inside the statement, only before